# How can all jqueryui autocompletes registered within a div be found?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a div which contains various unknown inputs.  Some of these inputs may or may not be registered as jqueryui autocomplete text inputs.  How can I find the autocomplete objects that are registered and destroy them using the .autocomplete('destroy') method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

The jQuery UI widgets (and other ones) built using the Widget Factory automatically defines a pseudo-selector:

```
$('input:ui-autocomplete').autocomplete('destroy');
```

and it will get the inputs that have an autocomplete instance attached.

Please note that is only working with widgets built using the [jQuery UI Widget Factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory) (and others that explicitly implement such behavior). Inside the jQuery UI library, a few widgets does not implement this factory, like Datepicker for instance, but Autocomplete does.

**Method 2**

The autocomplete plugin adds a css class `.ui-autocomplete-input' to the input fields that have been initialized by the plugin, so you can also do:

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').autocomplete('destroy');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your div has an ID, use the following selector: `#your_div_id .ui-autocomplete-input`